# Pitch Accent of てる / てない (Casual Speak)

Tags: pitch-accent

With respect to pitch accent, the negative form of いる{LH} is いない{LHH}, while the negative form of ある{HL} is ない{HL}. But what is the pitch of their shortened versions when used in てる / てない constructions? More specifically:

1. What is the pitch of "る" and "ない" when they are used as shortened versions of いる, ある, いない, and ない, respectively (in a てる/てない construction)?
2. Does the pitch of ”る” and "ない" in てる/てない change depending upon whether it is shortening いる{LH} or ある{HL}? Or is it the same pitches in either case?

Comment: In a similar vein to [your other question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96247/45489), it depends on whether the word is Heiban or not. る cannot be felt independent and it never changes the pitch. ない/いない may come with slight pitch change, esp. the latter is felt more independent.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I pronounce:

- みている【HLLL】 / ねている【LHHH】
- みてる【HLL】/ ねてる【LHH】
- みていない【HLLHH】/ ねていない【LHHHH】 (Also: みていない【HLLHL】 / ねていない【LHHHL】)
- みてない【HLHL】 / ねてない【LHHL】

So ている/てる works like a continuation of the verb, but ない works like an independent word with its own pitch accent.

Related:

- [Pitch Accent for ~ない and ~たい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66753/5010)
- [ない pitch accent](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94823/5010)
- [Pitch accent for ないで and なくて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73475/5010)