# Do Negative Downstepped i-adj's have accents on な?

Tags: i-adjectives, pitch-accent

Consider that 上手い is a downstepped i-adj (i.e., pronounced as うまい{LHL}).

**Question:** What are the pitch accents of the following negative conjugations of 上手い?

- 上手くない
- 上手くなかった
- 上手くなくて
- 上手くなければ
- 上手くなる (not a negative conjugation but Dogen includes this with the others; see below).

## According to OJAD: no accents on な's

According to OJAD, they're *all* accented on the first mora, with no accents on な:

[image]

[OJAD also has a "word conjugation table" page](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/word:%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B%E3%81%84), which shows an additionally correct pitch with accent on their second mora (but again no accents on the な):

[image]

## According to Dogen: additional accents *are* on な:

According to Dogen's pitch accent course, the rule for determining the pitch of negative i-adj is to conjugate the i-adj into its く-form, and then add ない{HL}, なかった{HLLL}, なくて{HLL},なければ{HLLL}, なる{HL}. Notice that in all of these cases, accents *are* on the な. This leads to the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So which is correct? Are they both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [日本語アクセント入門](https://www.sanseido-publ.co.jp/publ/gen/gen2lang/jgoacc_prm/), for non-Heiban (起伏型) words, there is a second downstep at な. That is, there is not a rise before な, it just goes down. In this sense, both are not exactly correct (OJAD doesn't show the down step (clearly) and the video shows a non/hardly-existent rise).

> p37. (adapted)
> 起伏型のナル形(ヨワクナル)は、.... 語句の頭のヨのところで下がり目が生じた後、接尾辞ナルの第１拍目の後ろで2度目の下降が生じている。このようなピッチパターンを図にしてみると、次のようになる。
>
> ```
> ヨ'
>
> 　　　ワク ナ'
>
> 　　　　　　　ル
> ```
>
> １つのアクセント単位の中に２つ以上の下降が生じた場合は、このテキストでは、1回の下降ごとに ] という記号をつけ、例えば[ヨ]ワクナ]ルのように示すことがある（[は急激な上昇を示す）。

This applies to other suffixes. The same book (p39) has

> 辛い　[カ]ラクナ]イ　 
> 怖い　[コ]ワクナ]イ
> 弱い　[ヨ]ワクナ]イ
> 強い　[ツ]ヨクナ]イ

---

I guess it depends on how much 'independence' is felt before ない (or other prefixes). If there is a complete rise before な, it does not sound like a suffix, but still ない IS perceived as independent to some extent, hence the down stepping.

Comment: I would say normally there is a rise up to the な, but it’s something like 1/3rd of the size of the initial drop so it definitely doesn’t make it all the way back up like the video’s graph suggests.

Comment: Apparently this is called down step (as a technical term). https://okwave.jp/qa/q2431150.html https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%83%E3%83%97