# Accent pattern of ています

Tags: pitch-accent, phonology, phonetics, linguistics

According to the rules of accent, a "flat" verb (平板式) keeps flat in its て-form, and a non-"flat" (起伏式) verb is accented in the antepenultimate position in the て-form:

> ア↑ビル（浴びる）→ ア↑ビテ
> タ↑ベ↓ル（食べる）→ タ↓ベテ

According to my books[*], ている-form keeps the accent location, so

> ア↑ビテイル、タ↓ベテイル

The suffix -ます is accented as マ↓ス no matter the main verb is flat or non-flat, its naturally to deduce:

> ア↑ビテイマ↓ス

but "タ↓ベテイル" is not a regular accent for simple verb[**], so I am not sure:

> タ↑ベテイマ↓ス (*treated like a simple verb*)
> タ↓ベテ・イ↑マ↓ス (*treated separately*)
> タ↓ベテイマス (*with the accent of -ます neglected*)

Which is(/are) correct?

---

[*] 三省堂 明解日本語アクセント辞典, and NHK 日本語発音アクセント辞典; neither talks about the case of "て+auxilary verb";
[**] Regularly verbs are either "flat" or accented penultimately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is タ↓ベテ・イ↑マ↓ス theoretically. ([The same question](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7478419.html) on goo)

But similar to the following question, the rise before マ is not full, so it is felt more like タ↓ベテ・イマ↓ス

- [Do Negative Downstepped i-adj's have accents on な?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96247/45489)

Comment: (Though not the same topic,) do verbs accented before penultimate mora have the similar pattern? ア↓イツグ（相次ぐ）→ ア↓イツイデ；ア↓イツギマ↓ス

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian Generally I think yes, the same applies to functional words like ます like I commented for ない in the linked answer.